# How to avoid Clojure function destructuring argument vector?

Tags: function, vector, clojure, arguments

I have an argument that keeps taking my vector argument and destructuring it, even as I try to avoid it several ways.

Error:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (5) passed to: core$build-par-sel$fn
```

Attempt 1:

```
(defn build-par-sel
  [& {:keys [^clojure.lang.PersistentVector par-vals best-val]}]
  ; Do stuff...
)
(let [best 100.0
          pars [1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0]]
      (let [par-sel (build-par-sel 
                           :par-vals pars
                           :best-val best)]))))
```

Attempt 2:

```
(defn build-par-sel
  [& {:keys [par-vals best-val]}]
  ; Do stuff...
)
(let [best 100.0
          pars [1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0]]
      (let [par-sel (build-par-sel 
                           :par-vals pars
                           :best-val best)]))))
```

Attempt 3:

```
(defn build-par-sel
  [par-vals best-val]
  ; Do stuff...
)
(let [best 100.0
          pars [1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0]]
      (let [par-sel (build-par-sel pars best)]))))
```

Comment: The exception you paste is reported to happen inside the definition of `build-par-sel`, in some anonymous function that build-par-sel creates - we can't solve this problem without seeing the body of that function.

Comment: @noisesmith Please make this as an answer. You were right. I was using `apply` instead of `mapv` inside `build-par-sel`. That explains my difficulty! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you paste is reported to happen inside the definition of `build-par-sel`, in some anonymous function that `build-par-sel` creates. We can't do more to solve this problem without seeing the body of that function.